# Mysql Update Database with radio button

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

Okay so I'm making a game and want it to be were the users have an amount of images to pick from to be there image. I have a column in the database that is user_image and it's default is 0 and if it's 0 it's an image. It's 0-3 and each number being an individual image. Like this..

```
<?php 
if ( $userp['user_image'] = 0 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="../achievements/Silver-Bank.png" width="60" height="60" title="Change Image"">';
} 
elseif ( $userp['user_image'] = 1  )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="../achievements/Silver-Missions.png" width="60" height="60" title="Change Image"">';
}
elseif ( $userp['user_image'] = 2 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="../achievements/Silver-Level.png" width="60" height="60" title="Change Image"">';
}
elseif ( $userp['user_image'] = 3 )
{
    echo 
    '<img src="../achievements/Diamond-Bank.png" width="60" height="60" title="Change Image"">';
}
?>
```

That's where the user's image is displayed. I made a page for the user to select the image with a radio button. Here it is with the PHP for updating the database and I can't seem to get it working.

```
<?php 
if ( isset ( $_POST['new_user_image'] ) )
{
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET user_image=(new_user_image) WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_affected_rows($connect) == 1) {
        echo 'User image sucessfully changed!';
    }
    else
{
}
}
?>
```

That's the PHP for it and not to be noobish but it's not letting me post the table and form?

Comment: I know the PHP is correct, pretty sure it is. I think it has to do with the form. I have the submit button in a different TD and I think it's affecting it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to check for a database error after you run mysql_query; something like:

   `if (mysql_errno()) { die(mysql_error()); }`
2. Using mysql_ functions at all are not recommended -- the php manual even has a big red message that tell you not to use them.  Use mysqli or pdo extensions instead.
3. The SQL statement you have isn't really valid SQL

`SET user_image=(new_user_image)`

That in no way indicates that you want to store the result of a variable in that column.  You need to do something like:

```
$sql = sprintf('UPDATE users SET user_image=%d WHERE id=%d', $_POST['new_user_image'], $id);
```

If you're ever unsure of your SQL, then at the very least print the text of the query with `echo $sql` and check to make sure it runs against the database directly.  You can much more easily get any SQL specific issue working there.

Comment: $new_user_image = $_POST['new_user_image'];